# View instanciated 2 times with CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView

Tags: c#, collectionviewsource

I have a ViewModel that I want to display. I use the command:

```
    var CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView (MyViewModel);
    if (CollectionView! = null)
        collectionView.MoveCurrentTo (MyViewModel);
```

The problem is that it create two instance of the view with the same instance of the ViewModel.

Someone has an idea of ​​my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't really make sense... the parameter of `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` is supposed to be some kind of collection, but you're passing a ViewModel. You should pass the collection that contains the ViewModel.

Comment: I have the solution.

In fact, as I load my view in a tabcontrol and I did not put a title for the tab, it creates 2 times the view, once the title of the tab and the other for the contained